# Find expiration date of Android keystore

Tags: android, keystore

I made a keystore a while ago for my Android apps but I can't remember how long I set the validity for.

Is there a way to find out how long the keystore is good for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you export a signed APK file from the ADT in Eclipse (assuming you are working in Eclipse), the `Export Android Application` dialog shows the keystore expiry date;

[image: Export Android Application showing the expiry date of keystore]

Answer (score 63):

You can use the keytool from the jdk to get certificate info. A command like this should work

```
keytool -list -v -keystore keystore.jks -alias mydomain
```

Replace

```
'keystore.jks' with your keystore name
'mydomain' with your alias name
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Gives information of when the key was generated and the estimated expiration date (year if above a year in length)

Comment: Omit the -alias parameter to list them all.

Comment: If you have a password on your keystore you can supply `-storepass $STOREPASS` to use a variable you've set with the password using a secure method so it doesn't leak into the shell history or process list.

Answer (score 0):

On your android studio terminal or from the gradle script selection (right top, click on gradle icon and run a script) run the command gradle signingReport After the completion, you can see after every key a message like "Valid until: ...."

Answer (score 0):

Goto the keystore path and enter the below code

keytool -list -v -alias aliasName -keystore keystoreName.keystore -storepass password