# Google Play - Package File is Invalid

Tags: android, google-play

I've developed an app a while ago and already uploaded it to google play a few months ago. It has about 2000 downloads at the moment and it seems to work fine for everyone.

But today someone sent me an email, I'm quoting him:

> I really wanted this app. but when I started downloading it I got the error message "package file is invalid". I thought this was my fault so I went and downloaded some other stuff which all downloaded fine. so I am hoping you nay be able to fix it! I have a sg3, version 4.1.2 and if you need more information, I will assist in any way!

I've recently (2 days ago) release an update for the app, it's been two days and the statistics say that no one downloaded the update yet.

I did some research and it says that this problem is caused by the user, not by the developer. Could anyone tell me if this can be fixed by me? Or should I tell him to clear his cache etc.?

[This is the app,](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.matthewstudios.gw2legendary) if anyone could take his time and download it just to see if it works :) thank you!

Keystore is not expired:

> Certificate expires on Wed Oct 14 22:17:12 CEST 3012

Also, I just asked my friend, that also has Samsung Galaxy S3 to try downloading it and he says it works good. So I'm pretty sure the problem isn't in the app, but in this user's phone. Any suggestions what I should tell him to try fixing?

Comment: did you sign your app with a valid keystore ? expired keystore might create such problems

Comment: @sureshcheemalamudi I'm pretty sure I did, when I was creating a keystore I set it to expire in a few years, and it's been around 2-3 months since I uploaded the app. Is there any way to confirm that the keystore is alright tho?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271466/find-expiration-date-of-android-keystore

Comment: @sureshcheemalamudi just checked it, it is not expired for sure

Comment: what is the build and maxSDKVersion of your app?

Comment: @OnurA. You mean target sdk version? It's 17. I have android 4.3 on my Galaxy Nexus and the app also works fine.

Comment: Just downloaded from PlayStore, installs fine on HTC One S (Android 4.1.1).

Comment: @bgse thanks a lot mate! It seems that it works fine everywhere, so I'm almost 100% sure now that the problem is in his phone. Does anyone have any idea what should I suggest him to try to fix the problem?

Comment: I know someone who has this problem sometimes when installing from the web store on the device. Installing from the native app works fine. Maybe that's related?

Comment: @Pizzret it is definitely about user's phone, in my view possible options; 1-his/her internet connection is poor so he/she can't complete the download hence downloaded package is incomplete thus it gives error
2- his/her device's memory is on the limit, he/she needs to make sure his/her device doesn't give any memory errors or memory is big enough to install app

Comment: Thanks for all the replies, I've already answered his mail, I told him that it's the phone's problem and provided him with some links to fix the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most likely not your or your application's fault. Tell this person to follow these instructions to solve the problem. Try one of these three links:

[Link 1](http://gizmostorm.com/how-to-fix-package-file-is-invalid-error-on-google-play-store/)

[Link 2](http://honharengineer.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-fix-package-file-is-invalid.html)

[Link 3](http://appslova.com/android-fix-package-file-is-invalid-error-in-google-play/)

Things you should try:

- Go to Settings --> Applications --> all applications --> Google Play Store --> clear data & clear cache
- Again go to the same path but this time delete updates
- Also, another possible problem I stumbled upon is that this mostly happens when you're trying to download by WIFI, so you might also want to mention that he should try downloading without wifi, by mobile data

Comment: In addition to the links, a summary of the steps involved would be nice.

Comment: Thank you very much, I answered the email, providing him with these links and information.

Comment: None of these worked. The only thing that worked was to go to the Whatsapp site, download the apk for android and install it manually. Interestingly enough, on the play store, the file was said to have 23MB and was failing on every try, but the download I did had 27MB, and only it worked.

Answer (score 0):

https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/3300875?hl=en

Updated on Aug 13 2013 basically it sometimes happens.
In my case a white-lable chinese dongle will load some apps aometimes and not others. ed OI file manager uploaded once, but ot a second time. Google Hangouts, G+ and SKY map never worked.

My own app installed from an email once, but failed a second time. There is a question as to which of the two package installers to use.

Sorry I can't be more helpful