# How to check the android keystore certificate expiration date? Any command to detect it?

Tags: android

How to check the android keystore certificate expiration date? 
Could someone please help me on this?

Comment: have your tried java keytool command.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271466/find-expiration-date-of-android-keystore

Answer (score 2):

```
KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
store.load(instream, key);
X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) store.getCertificate("alias");
Date exprireDate = certificate.getNotAfter();
```

Then use `exprireDate` for checking if certificate expired.

Answer (score 0):

On your android studio terminal or from the gradle script selection (right top, click on gradle icon and run a script) run the command
**gradle signingReport**
After the completion, you can see after every key a message like "Valid until: ...."

Answer (score 0):

To check the **keystore** expiry date from **Android Studio**

[image]

Go to **Gradle scripts** which will be on the top right corner of Android studio
Click on
**Tasks** -> **Android** -> **signingReport** run the script
Once build is finished click the run tab at the bottom and search for **Valid until** keyword